# Data input format for heatmaps

Tags: d3.js

Still fairly new to d3.js - I'd like to create a heatmap show the time it takes to travel between two destinations. Assuming that the final output should look something like this:

[image: this]

In R you could have your data in wide format as a data.matrix, and then throw it into gplots' heatmap.2 and get a nice heatmap. Does d3.js have any such capability, where I can have my data (either .csv or .json) brought in as wide format like this:

[image: this]

Or is generating a heatmap in d3.js a matter of iterating over rows and columns using two for loops to create boxes, and therefore I should use long format like this:

[image: this]

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSON data for a heatmap...something like this:

```
{
  travelTime: [
  { source: A,
    destination: A,
    time: 0
  },
  { source: A,
    destination: B,
    time: 3
  },
  { source: A,
    destination: C,
    time: 4
  }]
}
```

Your Y scale domain is based on `source` and your X scale based on `destination`